# App widget inconsistent sizing between tablet and phone

Tags: java, android, android-view, homescreen, android-appwidget

I am attempting to design an app which reproduces the shortcut styles of the standard app shortcut home screen icons but as a widget. Note, this is currently just looking at the standard Android homescreen.

I have made the following observations using the "Dump View Hierarchy for UI Automator" tool in the DDMS -> Devices view of Eclipse:
[image]

The space given in the 1 x 1 square changes depending on screen density, orientation and whether the phone home screen is in "phone mode" or "tablet mode" (start a 4.x emulator and you can tell by the background amongst other things). Screen density effects the size as expected (0.75, 1, 1.5, 2.0 density factor scaling), but the orientation and 'home screen mode' are quite unpredictable. Specifically:

---

**DIMENSIONS FOR A 1x1 'SQUARE' ON THE HOMESCREEN**

**Phone mode:**

- Portrait: *80dp x 100dp = 4:5 aspect ratio*
- Landscape (if available - not thoroughly tested): *106dp x 74dp = 53:37 aspect ratio*

**Tablet mode:**

- Portrait: *96dp x 96dp = 1:1 aspect ratio*
- Landscape: *96dp x 96dp = 1:1 aspect ratio*

---

As you can see, there is barely any consistency whatsoever, but these are the dimensions given to a 'square' on the home screen. It gets **even worse** when looking at the space actually given to widgets (yes, it does differ from the square space available and **used** by the system shortcut widgets):

---

**DIMENSIONS GIVE TO A WIDGET IN A 1x1 'SQUARE'**

**Phone mode:**

- Portrait: *80dp x 100dp = 4:5 aspect ratio*
- Landscape (if available - not thoroughly tested): *90dp x 58dp = 45:29 aspect ratio*

**Tablet mode:**

- Portrait: *72dp x 72dp = 1:1 aspect ratio*
- Landscape: *72dp x 72dp = 1:1 aspect ratio*

---

So I'm stuck with:

- Inconsistent aspect ratios between phone and tablet modes
- Smaller areas given for an app widget then that of an app shortcut in some cases. Consequently, the relative and perceived size of widgets will look very different on a tablet vs phone?
- The smaller areas aren't even vertically centred, they are mostly top aligned with a 2dp top margin which means they don't even look aligned with a neighbouring application shortcut to start with, let alone when trying to produce a similar looking shortcut through a widget

To visualise, the following images show a default system shortcut (with a red box surrounding showing the 'square dimensions - which both system shortcuts and widgets always share). Next to it is my widget with the blue highlight showing the bounds of a `MATCH_PARENT` setup, hence where the widget can actually draw within its 'square':

Phone -  Port: [image]

Tablet - Land: [image]

Tablet - Port: [image]

Most important to take from here, is the blue area of the widgets on a tablet does not even **include the space** where the system shortcut draws its text?

Does anyone have insights into:

1. Why the home screen is so inconsistent?
2. Why app widgets are not given the same drawing space as that of a system shortcut / or should it be and I am doing something wrong?
3. Should I be doing something else, or is it just accepted that for a 1x1 widget which takes up all its given drawing space, it will look 'smaller' (compared to its surroundings) on a tablet than it would on a phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And even better, many launchers allow the user to customize the size of their grid. Per the [design guidelines for App Widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy_determining_size), you cannot rely on an exact size on all devices. Instead, determine a minimum width and height and let the home screen determine how many squares the layout takes up.

They do provide some guidance on what you can expect for the minimum size of a cell (and all your numbers are much larger than that it seems), but again custom launchers may reduce this minimum even lower.

I find it best to focus on what components need to be in your layout (buttons, etc) and then follow the [Metrics and Grids design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/style/metrics-grids.html) to determine your minimal size (noting the margins are automatically added on Android 4.0+ devices but not on <4.0 devices). Then make sure your layouts are dynamic enough to fill in the space provided to them (centering text, etc as appropriate). Remember widgets are assumed to be a framed, single entry, rather than floating text as noted on the [App Widget Design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html#anatomy).

Comment: Yes, most annoying, I haven't even looked at Samsung, HTC, etc screens as well. I accept your points on correct procedure, I am just still mainly wanting to know the exact reason why a widget is given a different amount of space then that of a shortcut on the same screen with the same density, launcher app, model etc when both are allocated one 'square' on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can manage the scree sizes in layouts you want to create different layouts for different screen sizes and also for landscape and portrait .

create the following layouts in your resource folder like this :

layout-large

layout-small

layout-xlarge

layout-landscape

And then copy your XML files in to it and check in preview screens for different devices you can have a idea based on that you can modify the size of the widgets in your homescreen.